# Contando o número de conexões por IP a um servidor web na porta 80. Está correta a regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-2.7

Gostaria de contar o número de conexões por IP  por segundo (na porta 80) a um servidor web cujo IP é 192.168.1.216. A entrada para a contagem é um arquivo de dump de rede no formato PCAP (arquivo.pcap) gerado com tcpdump.
A saída será direcionada para o arquivo contagem.txt

A seguinte expressão regular (regex) está correta? O que acham?

Arquivo PCAP: https://ufile.io/y5c7k

```
tcpdump -anr arquivo.pcap host 192.168.1.216 and port 80 |
    sed -une '
      s/^\(.\{8\}\).* IP \(.*\)\.[0-9]\+ > 192.168.1.216.80: Flags \[S\],.*/\1 \2/p
    ' |
    sort | uniq -c >contagem.txt
```

Exemplo de entrada:

[image: Entrada]

Exemplo de uma saída:

```
      1 07:50:00 192.168.1.107
      1 07:50:00 192.168.1.108
      1 07:50:00 192.168.1.110
      1 07:50:00 192.168.1.121
      1 07:50:00 192.168.1.128
      1 07:50:00 192.168.1.129
      1 07:50:00 192.168.1.130
      1 07:50:00 192.168.1.138
      1 07:50:00 192.168.1.140
      1 07:50:00 192.168.1.143
      1 07:50:00 192.168.1.148
      1 07:50:00 192.168.1.153
      1 07:50:00 192.168.1.160
      1 07:50:00 192.168.1.169
      1 07:50:00 192.168.1.170
      1 07:50:00 192.168.1.176
```

A soma depois é feita com um script Python:

```
with open('contagem.txt') as f: linhas = f.readlines()

soma = 0
for linha in linhas: soma += int(linha.strip().split(" ")[0])

print(soma)
```

A expressão regular (regex) está correta? O que acham?

Comment: Semuma amostra do tipo de aruqivo que voc^quer ler, vai sermuito dificil algue responder a questão. Busca de arquivos "pcap" no google resultam em arquivos cplexo,s comd ados binários misturados -  algu[em teria que achar a especificação, ler, entende,r enteder a sua expereesão regular e ai dar uma resposta.

Comment: Agora, ja que vocẽ colocou a tag Python, adianto que provavelemten voc~e vai poder fazer uns script python de 5-10 linhas que vai ser muito mais legível e fácilde manter do que a abordagem que você está tentando

Comment: @jsbueno: vou colocar um exemplo de arquivo (link): https://ufile.io/y5c7k

Comment: @Paz: Você conseguiria sugerir alguma forma diferente de fazer a regex ou um script python?

Comment: @EdS qual campo da imagem que é a entrada? ela vem toda concatenada? coloca um exemplo aí por escrito que acho que consigo bolar algo bom pra ti!

Comment: @Paz: A entrada é o arquivo dump de rede que dei um print. O arquivo está disponível aqui -> https://ufile.io/y5c7k